# C++ destructor segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have a newbie question about c++ and destructors. My c++ program gives a segmentation fault after I delete a class pointer if I have declared a destoructor, otherwise I don't and I do not understand why. Help is much appreciated.

main file, where the class is used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int iargc, char *iargv[]){
    std::cout<<"helloworld"<<std::endl;

    foo *test;
    test =  new foo[2];
    delete test;

}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
class foo{
    public:
        foo();
        ~foo();
};
#define FOO_H
#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

foo::foo(){
};

foo::~foo(){
};
```

without a delete statement, no problems whatsoever, if I remove the destructor from the header file and the source code, I can delete the class pointer test, but I cannot delete it, while I declared the destructor like this without a segfault.

Comment: The code is wrong because it does `delete` instead of `delete[]` but that should not cause a seg fault in the minimal code you posted.  So I think you left out something about what you tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `delete[] test`, in the array form.